# Problem installing Rails 2.3.2 and version_requirements fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Previously I haven't got such a problem with Rails 2.3.2 installation. Somebody have any suggestions how can I fix that?

`$ ruby script/server

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000

/home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:99:in 'requirement': undefined local variable or method 'version_requirements' for # (NameError)

```
from /home/thesis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:254:in 'activate'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1204:in 'gem'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:57:in 'add_load_paths'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:299:in 'add_gem_load_paths'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:299:in 'each'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:299:in 'add_gem_load_paths'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:132:in 'process'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in 'send'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/initializer.rb:113:in 'run'
from /home/thesis/development/tt/my_app/config/environment.rb:15
from /home/thesis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in 'gem_original_require'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in 'require'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in 'require'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in 'new_constants_in'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in 'require'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@my_app/gems/rails-2.3.2/lib/commands/server.rb:84
from /home/thesis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in 'gem_original_require'
from /home/thesis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in 'require'
from script/server:3`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put below code in your environment.rb. it might be solved your problem

```
if Gem::VERSION >= "1.3.6"
    module Rails
      class GemDependency
        def requirement
          r = super
          (r == Gem::Requirement.default) ? nil : r
        end
      end
    end
  end
```